# Using mappings in CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy

In the ["Dispatching / Other Dispatchers"](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/concepts/dispatching.html#other-dispatchers) section of the CherryPy documentation, there is an example of Django-style regular-expression-to-view-function mapping definition, but there is no indication on how to attach this to `cherrypy.tree`.

How are you supposed to register this mapping?

**Edit**: Based on the ["regex URL mapping" thread](https://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-users/browse_thread/thread/93374eabe6681a9e?pli=1) in the `cherrypy-users` Google group, I could figure out that to attach views using regular expressions, you need to use [`routes`](http://routes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)-style mapping using the `cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher` class like so:

```
def hello(name='stranger'):
    """Sample view."""
    return 'Hello, %s!'%name

dispatch = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
dispatch.connect('hello-1', '/hello', hello)
dispatch.connect('hello-2', '/hello/{name:([^/]+)}', hello)
cherrypy.tree.mount(None, config={
        '/': {
             'request.dispatch': dispatch,
            }
        })
```

Note the `{argument-name:regular-expression}` syntax in the URL pattern.

Is there a way to specifiy the route patterns using the list-of-pairs syntax as shown in the CherryPy documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not any extra step required. During a request, `cherrypy.tree` performs a first routing stage, where the incoming request is mapped to an Application using its path-to-app mapping. When you call `tree.mount(root=None, script_name='/', config=conf)` at startup, the Tree creates a cherrypy.Application for you behind the scenes and mounts it at '/'.

Once the Application is found, its config takes over, and the "request.dispatch" config for the example app in the docs says "use the RoutesDispatcher for all URI's in this app". That RoutesDispatcher instance will then pass control of the request to the appropriate Controller.

*The regex example in the docs isn't even that well-developed. You'd need to **write** a Dispatcher which uses it. That process "only" needs to find the handler and collect request.config, but those two activities can be very complex depending on the dispatch style chosen. See the existing dispatchers for inspiration.*

Comment: Did you look at [the example](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/concepts/dispatching.html#other-dispatchers) I referred to?  The `mappings` variable is not passed to `cherrypy.tree`.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand your question :) That "example" isn't really prescriptive, it's just there to illustrate what the map itself might look like for a regular-expression-based solution. To finish it, you would have to write a Dispatcher subclass which used it to return a page handler and collect the config for the current request. That process is so varied for different styles, it's hard to show you how for a particular style without doing it all myself. ;) But there are the existing dispatchers in `_cpdispatch.py` to help get started.

Comment: I had already looked at `_cpdispatch.py` and definitely did not find a dispatcher supporting such a list of regex-handler mappings :-)  So, basically, CherryPy has no built-in support for Django-style dispatcher  as in the example.  I get it.  If you make this clear in your answer, I'll accept it.