# cherrypy - URL dispatcher

Tags: cherrypy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using mappings in CherryPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142625/using-mappings-in-cherrypy)

How would I map a url regEx such as /data/[A-Z].txt to a resource in cherrypy? Is there an simple example somewhere? I don't get the docs here.

http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/RestfulDispatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [RoutesDispatcher](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/test/test_routes.py)

```
import cherrypy

class City:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.population = 10000

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, **kwargs):
        return "Welcome to %s, pop. %s" % (self.name, self.population)

    @cherrypy.expose
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        self.population = kwargs['pop']
        return "OK"

d = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
d.connect(action='index', name='hounslow', route='/hounslow', controller=City('Hounslow'))
d.connect(action='index', name='surbiton', route='/surbiton', controller=City('Surbiton'),
          conditions=dict(method=['GET']))
d.mapper.connect('/surbiton', controller='surbiton',
                 action='update', conditions=dict(method=['POST']))

conf = {'/': {'request.dispatch': d}}
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 5000})
cherrypy.tree.mount(root=None, config=conf)
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

You might test this with a browser on http://127.0.0.1:5000/surbiton 
You can test the POST command with curl:

```
curl -i -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/surbiton
curl -i -d "pop=100" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/surbiton
curl -i -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/surbiton
```

There is the documentaton from the [Routes project](http://routes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Or this example from [appmecha](http://appmecha.wordpress.com/2008/10/27/cherrypy-gae-routing-2/).