# Map specific url to response with Cherrypy?

Tags: python, routes, cherrypy

I'm writing a web app with CherryPy and I need to map the URL /.well-known/acme-challenge/KH5LEgbLPhDrhJ-BAf7cyTXe8qcN6kL4CJQMOLe1fXU
to the response KH5LEgbLPhDrhJ-BAf7cyTXe8qcN6kL4CJQMOLe1fXU.8bOE0CjbktH8JYB_jq5aFEqbG-37XhHjDAIhWppNkdQ inorder to obtain a ssl certificate.

I've tried using an alias such like

```
cherrpypy.expose("/.well-known/acme-challenge/KH5LEgbLPhDrhJ-BAf7cyTXe8qcN6kL4CJQMOLe1fXU")
def ssl_cert_map(self):
    return "KH5LEgbLPhDrhJ-BAf7cyTXe8qcN6kL4CJQMOLe1fXU.8bOE0CjbktH8JYB_jq5aFEqbG-37XhHjDAIhWppNkdQ"
```

however when I try to access it at /.well-known/acme-challenge/KH5LEgbLPhDrhJ-BAf7cyTXe8qcN6kL4CJQMOLe1fXU I get a 404 error.
How would I be able to make it so /.well-known/acme-challenge/KH5LEgbLPhDrhJ-BAf7cyTXe8qcN6kL4CJQMOLe1fXU gives me KH5LEgbLPhDrhJ-BAf7cyTXe8qcN6kL4CJQMOLe1fXU.8bOE0CjbktH8JYB_jq5aFEqbG-37XhHjDAIhWppNkdQ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the URL in the `cherrypy.expose` method. The expose method exposes your class method to be used by Cherrypy.

In order to map your URL to a specific method, you gotta use the `RoutesDispatcher`.

example:

```
import cherrypy

class Root:

    cherrpypy.expose
    def ssl_cert_map(self):
        return "KH5LEgbLPhDrhJ-BAf7cyTXe8qcN6kL4CJQMOLe1fXU.8bOE0CjbktH8JYB_jq5aFEqbG-37XhHjDAIhWppNkdQ"

app_dispatcher = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()

app_dispatcher.connect(
name='ssl-cert',
route='/.well-known/acme-challenge/KH5LEgbLPhDrhJ-BAf7cyTXe8qcN6kL4CJQMOLe1fXU',
action='ssl_cert_map',
controller=Root())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    server_config = {
        '/': {
            'request.dispatch': app_dispatcher
        }
    }
    cherrypy.tree.mount(root=None, config=server_config)
    cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Reference: [cherrypy - URL dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484206/cherrypy-url-dispatcher)